# Using Workflow and Pocos to create an EDI x12 document

Tags: c#, workflow, poco, edi

I'm currently working on a project where I need to develop an EDI x12 document. Currently all the data lives within the database spread across a number of tables. My first step was to create a number of POCO objects to better assemble and group the data. (For example, my claim object has a List of Service Objects). I'm lost at the next step of the process which is to then take my collection of nicely organized POCOs and output them as a EDI x12.

Since a lot of fields within the x12 format depends on the value of other fields, I first thought was to create an used a workflow for doing so. Being new to workflows however, I'm wondering if this is even the right approach? If so, any recommendations on laying out the workflow?

EDIT: Tried to better describe my problem and question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to generate a x12 document directly?
maybe using an edi translator is an option.

usually when doing edi there a several steps involved:
- generate a inhouse file with the right content 
  (the real content, not all of the x12 codes and qualifiers)
- the edi translator does all the x12 formatting and adding of x12 specific codes.